# find max or min in excel, with conditions

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, max, minimum

In my spreadsheet I have a column with negative and positive values.  I need to get the minimum among all positive values and the maximum among all negative ones.  How can I do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Find min/max values in a column among those matched from another column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904092/excel-find-min-max-values-in-a-column-among-those-matched-from-another-column)

Comment: How exactly can a question from 2011 with an answer given in 2011 be a duplicate of a question asked in 2015?

Comment: As per many other threads (I will later look for them) a "duplicate" in SO/SE does not require a later date than the "original"; it might be a misnomer. The criterion is that the "original" would have more answers, and/or more "quality", as per the upvotes of the question and answers. Such a measure is not univocally specified, although a formula could be put together. And it's not that I agree with a criterion like that (I see pros and cons for that), but only that I have seen quite a few people supporting it. The point is that people finding this OP get to the answers posted in the other.

Comment: Oh all right, I see now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use array formulas.  In the following examples, the values you're checking are in `A2:A10`.

Maximum negative:

```
=MAX(IF(A2:A10<0,A2:A10))
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering the formula.  Formula will then appear bracketed by {...}.

Minimum positive:

```
=MIN(IF(A2:A10>=0,A2:A10))
```

Also enter as an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: You should note that there is a corner case where this formula will return misinformation; in the case where the IF condition does not match anything (0 records meet the criteria), it will return 0 instead of what should be #N/A, e.g. `=MIN( IF(FALSE, 99) )` == 0