# Excel: Find min/max values in a column among those matched from another column

Tags: excel, lookup-tables

I have a table with two columns, say A:B.
I have a separate list (in column D) of all different values in column A.
For each target value in column D, I want to find, among all rows whose col A matches the target, the minimum and maximum values in column B.
For example, if data is as shown,

```
    col A   col B        col D
 1  7.5     1.00         7.5      1.00   1.20
 2  7.5     1.04         8        1.08   1.45
 3  7.5     1.08         8.5      1.17   1.83
 4  7.5     1.15
 5  7.5     1.20
 6  8       1.08
 7  8       1.13
 8  8       1.20
 9  8       1.29
10  8       1.38
11  8       1.43
12  8       1.45
13  8.5     1.17
14  8.5     1.22
15  8.5     1.26
16  8.5     1.35
17  8.5     1.42
18  8.5     1.51
19  8.5     1.58
20  8.5     1.64
21  8.5     1.69
22  8.5     1.74
23  8.5     1.79
24  8.5     1.83
```

I want to have formulas that return the last two columns (min and max).

Notes:

1. It would be convenient to have something that works even when referring to ranges going beyond the last row (e.g., using `$A$8:$A$50` in formulas, not necessarily `$A$8:$A$24`), so that new data can be added at the bottom of columns A,B and everything gets updated automatically.
2. Columns A,B will actually contain other data, headers, etc., so I guess some formulas may not work with references to whole columns like `$A:$A`.

**EDIT**: I have just found a few similar/related posts

[Find MIN/MAX date in a range if it matches criteria of other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746792/excel-find-min-max-date-in-a-range-if-it-matches-criteria-of-other-columns)

[Conditional Min and Max in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570223/conditional-min-and-max-in-excel-2010)

[select min value in B column for same values in A columns excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879653/select-min-value-in-b-column-for-same-values-in-a-columns-excel)

[Given value in column A, find min/max in column B in EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383047/given-value-in-column-a-find-min-max-in-column-b-in-excel)

[find max or min in excel, with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666057/find-max-or-min-in-excel-with-conditions)

Comment: How does a pivot table sound like to you?

Comment: @Jerry - It is an option. Downsides: 1) it does not get automatically updated when adding/changing source data, 2)  (perhaps minor, but still makes work uneasy) it appears to not work with the specific headers I have (merged cells).

Comment: That can be considered as an advantage or disadvantage too! If the results keep getting updated, you'll loose a lot of time each time data is inserted as the calculations are being updated again and again, whereas with a pivot table, you get to update once the data is updated with a single press of a button. For the second one though, yes, PivotTables don't work too well with merged cells, but I tend to think that one rarely requires merged cells.

Comment: @pnuts - +1 for Centre Across Selection. But it is not available for vertical centering (and I recall seeing a discussion in SO about this).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me.

for min:

```
=MIN(IF(($A$1:$A$50=D1),($B$1:$B$50)))
```

for max:

```
=MAX(IF(($A$1:$A$50=D1),($B$1:$B$50)))
```

Note, that it is an array formulas, so you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: It works. Is there any difference (even minor) with the answer by user3157280? If so, I missed it.

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: @pnuts, my answer was posted first

Comment: @pnuts, the main that OP got the answer to his question:)

Comment: I agree 100%: the main point is having good answers, the focus is there. It is, in addition, good to clarify the other point.

Comment: You should note that there is a corner case where this formula will return misinformation; in the case where the IF condition does not match anything (0 records meet the criteria), it will return 0 instead of what should be #N/A, e.g. `=MIN(IF(FALSE, 99))` == 0

Answer (score 3):

You can use array formulas to give you the answers you need.

For the min you can use the formula in cell E1:

```
{=MIN(IF($A:$A=D1,$B:$B))}
```

and the max the formula for cell F1 is :

```
{=MAX(IF($A:$A=D1,$B:$B))}
```

To enter an array formula, you should enter everything except the braces (the curly brackets) then press the Ctrl and Shift keys when you press the enter key... this will add the braces and the formula will be considered an array formula.

Once entered, you can copy the formula down for the other matched values

Array formulas work by calculating every combination.  It will calculate if the value in A1 is the same as D1, and if it is it will give the value of B1, then if the value of A2 is the same as D1 it will give the value of B2, and so on.  This will give you a list (or array) of values from the B column where the value in A is a match.  The MIN/MAX is then calculated as normal.

Comment: I tested it, it works. I think I tried this one among others, I was missing CSE.

Comment: Is there any reason for posting the same answer as another one already posted? Is it for the added explanation?

Comment: It took some time to type out - when I started this answer there where no answers.

Answer (score 2):

The `INDEX` function can help you avoid CSE by building a standard formula using some math to either zero or make astronomical any non-matching values depending upon whether you are looking for a `MAX` or `MIN` result.

The pseudo-MAXIF formula is a little easier so I'll start there.

```
=MAX(INDEX(B:B*(A:A=D1), , ))
```

Excel treats any boolean TRUE statement as *1* and any FALSE as *0* when used mathematically. Multiplying a value in column B by *1* leaves the value unchanged; multiplying by *0* will result in zero. The `INDEX` function passes an array of unchanged values and zeroes into the `MAX` function depending upon whether that match the criteria or not. The result will be the maximum value from column B where column A is equal to the criteria.

The pseudo-MINIF formula essentially flips the process around by mathematically excluding any non-matching value, leaving only matching values from which to choose a `MIN` from.

```
=MIN(INDEX(B:B+(A:A<>D1)*1E+99, , ))
```

Again, TRUE is *1* and FALSE is *0* but this time we are using it to add 1E+99 (a *1* followed by *99* zeroes which isn't going to be the `MIN` of anything) to any non-matching values. Matching values will have *0 × 1E+99* added to them which equates to zero and will not change their value.

[image: MAXIF and MINIF with standard formulas]

The full column cell range references I've used do not negatively impact calculation lag any more than a similar *array formula* would.

Answer (score -1):

You can have the references calculate themselves, assuming there are no gaps in the data, using named ranges.
e.g.

> ARange =OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNT($A:$A))
>   BRange =OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNT($A:$A))

(I use the same **COUNT** in both to ensure the areas are the same size)

<strike>Now I can use an array formula `=MAX((ARange=D2)*(BRange))` to get the max (and same for min).

Array Formulas are entered with CTRL+SHIFT+Enter</strike>
See @Simoco's answer for the correct formula

Comment: it doesen't work. It returns 0 for min (if all values are positive) and 0 for max (if all values are negative)

Comment: @simoco, yes, you are right. I will leave in the info about named ranges, but your answer works in all cases.