# Conditional Maximum in Excel using Array Formulae - how to ignore Blank Rows

Tags: excel, array-formulas

There are quite a few questions on Stack Overflow about doing a conditional MIN and MAX in Excel
e.g. [Excel: Find min/max values in a column among those matched from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904092/excel-find-min-max-values-in-a-column-among-those-matched-from-another-column?lq=1)

However, I don't think the following question is covered.

Normally the MIN and MAX functions will ignore blank rows, however it seems that if used in conjunction with a conditional array formula then they will NOT ignore.

For instance

[image]

If I enter the array formula `=MAX(IF(A1:A8="A",B1:B8))` then I get zero, when I really want to see -1, since of all the non-blank 'A' rows, the maximum is -1.

I thought that the following array formula would work `=MAX(IF(AND(A1:A8="A",B1:B8<>""),B1:B8))`  but it ALWAYS returns zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly had it! However, in an array formula, you cannot replicate an "AND" construction so straightforwardly, in essence since the return from the AND function is always a single value, never an array.

Hence, your attempt:

`=MAX(IF(AND(A1:A8="A",B1:B8<>""),B1:B8))`

would initially correctly resolve to (using the values you posted):

`=MAX(IF(AND({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE},{TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}),B1:B8))`

though the AND function would then look at that those two arrays of Boolean TRUE/FALSE returns and return a single value, i.e. FALSE (since there is at least one FALSE amongst those 16 entries).

The correct syntax would be:

`=MAX(IF(A1:A8="A",IF(B1:B8<>"",B1:B8)))`

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your explanation about the AND function returning only a single value!

Comment: any idea how to use the LEFT function inside the equation? I have scores that are 1-very unhappy, 2-unhappy, 3- neutral, 4-happy, 5-very happy
I tried with no luck, keep getting 0:
=MAX(IF(A1:A8="A",IF(B1:B8<>"",LEFT(B1:B8,1))))

Comment: Apologies for late reply. Do you still require help with this new query?

Answer (score 1):

you can test for blank in the if, and substitute an appropriate value if found.

The Array formula `=MAX(IF(A1:A8="a",IF(ISBLANK(B1:B8),-999,B1:B8)))` will substitute the value -999 for any blank cells, allowing you to find you maximum - alter the -999 depending on how low your numbers get